# Angular callback scope.apply

Tags: javascript, angular.js, callback, socket.io

Usually the socket.io's `on` method is like this:

```
socket.on('/msg', function(data){});
```

But in Angular that callback has to be wrapped inside its `$rootScope.$apply()` method otherwise anything that happens in the callback (like changing `$scope` properties) doesn't update in Angular.

Here's a simple way to do that:

```
function socketFactory($rootScope) {
    return {
        emit: socket.emit.bind(socket),
        on: function(msg, callback) {
            socket.on(msg, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    callback.apply(socket, arguments)
                });
            });
        },
    };
};
```

I was able to shorten this a little bit:

```
on: function(msg, callback) {
    socket.on(msg, function() {
        $rootScope.$apply(callback.apply(socket, arguments));
    });
},
```

I'm not sure if it'll go any further but I tried:

```
on: function(msg, callback) {
    socket.on(msg, $rootScope.$apply.apply(null, callback));
},
```

which threw an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined socket.io.js:1194

I'm guessing `$apply.apply` doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than giving a callback, why not broadcast to the rootScope and listen for that event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) should've been used here instead of [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
on: function(msg, callback) {
    socket.on(msg, $rootScope.$apply.bind($rootScope, callback.bind.apply(socket, arguments)));
},
```

But seeing how complicated the shortened "one-liner" becomes, expanded form was probably better:

```
on: function(msg, callback) {
    socket.on(msg, function(data){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            callback(data);
        });
    });
},
```